# Fill dynamic space with colour when using margin: auto;

Tags: css, html

I have a container DIV that centres itself with a width of 90%. It has a min-width of 940px and a max-width of 1240px.

Within this DIV I have a left side bar that is fixed and has a height of 100%. I want the colour from this DIV to continue to the left edge of the screen.

I can't add another DIV in because the margin is auto, and the min and max-height make the margin completely dynamic.

I have tried using a thick border on the container DIV but it acts as a margin in the sense that it doesn't go beyond the screen, it just moves the container DIV.

The current sidebar is where the content will be. This needs to stay where it is so everything appears centred on the page.

CSS Code:

```
#contain-content {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 940px;
    max-width: 1240px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#contain-content #left-panel {
    position: fixed;
    width: 330px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #183950;
    padding-top: 115px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YwN8v

Maximise your browser window. The section I am referring to is the space to the left of the side bar.

Comment: Can you prepare a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and provide us your markup?!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YwN8v/ Done, if you maximise your browser window, the space I am referring to is the bit to the left of the left side bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about gradient background of the body filling its left 5% with the needed color?
http://jsfiddle.net/YwN8v/2/

```
body {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #183950 0%, #183950 6%, transparent 6%);
}
```

**Update**

Here's a good tool to make gradients: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/, but it's better to copy-paste only the needed values from its output:

```
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(24,57,80,1) 0%, rgba(38,69,90,1) 6%, rgba(40,71,92,0) 7%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(24,57,80,1)), color-stop(6%,rgba(38,69,90,1)), color-stop(7%,rgba(40,71,92,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(24,57,80,1) 0%,rgba(38,69,90,1) 6%,rgba(40,71,92,0) 7%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(24,57,80,1) 0%,rgba(38,69,90,1) 6%,rgba(40,71,92,0) 7%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(24,57,80,1) 0%,rgba(38,69,90,1) 6%,rgba(40,71,92,0) 7%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
```

Comment: Thank you very much that seems to work, but what sort of compatibility are we looking at here? Do you think that would work in IE9?

Comment: Nevermind, just realised I can use a background image. Thank you!

Oh and thanks for the colorzilla link, I use it already and its amazing.

Comment: @yckart: Colorzilla's gradient editor is really good thing, but it's not a silver bullet. It generates much redundant code (e.g. `-ms-linear-gradient` is never used in practice, because IE9 doesn't support it and all shipped IE10 versions support unprefixed gradient, this was needed only for experiments with IE10 beta). And IE9- filter is appropriate only for limited cases for smooth transition between 2 colors, in other cases (like this) it just makes problem. So I don't agree with your edit, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Simply! Just add `left: 0` to your `#left-panel`-sidebar:

```
#contain-content #left-panel {
    position: fixed;
    width: 330px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #183950;
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-top: 115px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/YwN8v/3/

Comment: Thanks for your help but that would move all the sidebar content to the left. The actual content needs to stay where it is.